# NPM Install node not creating node_modules in current directory

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Using nvm for a specific project

- node 6.5.0
- npm 6.1.0
- package.json already does exist in local directory

When I am in the current directory for my project I run npm install and see it added one package from one contributor
[current directory npm install result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dslKU.png)

when I look at nvm -> v6.5.0 -> lib -> node_modules I see this [nvm location result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJWhk.png). I have tried also using the most up to date version of node and running npm i -g npm and saw the same result. Anyone encounter a similar issue and has found a solution? Any help would be great...Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The npm install is not honoring anything in the package.json and no node_modules created in local directory.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: want to see the node_modules in the current directory. I see the node_modules in the lib folder so why is not placing the same in this local project?

Comment: Are you running `npm install` from the directory that has `package.json`?

Comment: That is correct. I am running npm install from the directory that has package.json.

Comment: @SLaks so I updated to run `yarn` as opposed to `npm install` and it achieves what I am looking to do. Node version does need to be higher than 6.5.0. This is a work around but not a solution to the original problem when running node at 6.5.0.